# Google map javascript infoWindow empty

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm trying to display the infoWindow from a Marker in google Map API.

When I click on it, the bubble of info window appears but it's empty. However, I'm pretty sure it contains all data because the size of the bubble change according to the content it should display. Moreover, I can well print data into the console by the click.

It looks like the font's color is transparent...

```
addMarkersToMap(alert) {

    let position = new google.maps.LatLng(alert.latitude, alert.longitude);
    let mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: this.map,
      title: alert.alertTitle,
      latitude: alert.latitude,
      longitude: alert.longitude,
      icon : new google.maps.MarkerImage("../assets/icon/point.png")
    });
    

    mapMarker.setMap(this.map);
    this.addInfoWindowToMarker(mapMarker);
  }
  
  


addInfoWindowToMarker(marker) {

      let infoWindowContent = '<div id="content">' + 
                              '<h2 id="firstHeading" class"firstHeading">' + marker.title +'</h2>' +
                              '<p> Latitude: ' +marker.latitude +' </p>' +
                              '<p> Longitude: ' +marker.longitude +' </p>'
                              '</div>';
  
        let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: infoWindowContent
        });
  

    
        
    marker.addListener('click', () => {
      
      console.log(marker.title)
      console.log(marker.latitude)
      infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });
    this.infoWindows.push(infoWindow);
    
    }
```

Comment: is it a styling issue? maybe your css should be adjusted, or is it a javascript issue, infoWindow not added at all? It is not clear from your question

Comment: also maybe better to use css classes to style infoWindow content instead of ids as ids should be unique and you seem to add multiple different infoWindows which use same html ids

Comment: When I click on a marker, the bubble appear well but it's empty. I can't see the data. However, bubbles size of each marker change according to the info it should display.

Comment: if you select the content of the bubble with your mouse, do you see text inside, or if you inspect the element in browser console? It may well be simply a styling issue..

Comment: No. When I select the content of the bubble, nothing appears. The bubble appears only when I click on the marker with the mouse but it's empty.

Comment: [mcve] is what you need to provide!